# Push Notification Dialog displaying Even without aps-environment

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

We have an app in the App Store that QA insists is displaying prompts for permission to send push notifications to users. (The " would like to send you notifications" popup.)

The application in question *does* include push notification registration code (that shouldn't be active, but clearly might be), however the app is signed with a provisioning profile that does not support the aps-environment sandbox entitlement. I can verify this on the uploaded build with codesign -d --entitlements and confirming that aps-environment is not there.

In our previous experience (and we've shipped 11 updates to this app) simply signing without push notification entitlement is sufficient to stop the push notification dialog appearing.

It is tedious to remove all of the notification registration code as it is part of a 3rdparty library that we do use.

QA claims this only happens on iOS8 devices, although they are continuing testing.

I realize this is the opposite of most push notification questions (where users aren't able to see the push notification request popup that they want to see.)

Does anyone know of any change in iOS8 (or otherwise) that would allow an app to display the "foo would like to send you notifications" dialog *without* having aps-environment present? This would seem like a strange change for Apple to make.

Answer (score 1):

There is a new method in iOS 8 called `registerUserNotificationSettings`for `[UIApplication sharedApplication]`. Try to look for something like

```
UIUserNotificationType types = UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert;

UIUserNotificationSettings *notificationSettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:nil];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];
```

in `appDelegate` and remove it to silence the permission request.